# NativeScript + Vue : Core Theme / How to set ActionItem blue color

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, uinavigationbar, color-scheme

I am using the nativescript Core Theme.

my app.js: (I use the Light-Theme or Dark-Theme and it works fine)

```
import Theme from "@nativescript/theme";

Theme.setMode(Theme.Light); // Or Theme.Light

// Importing the global css file
import "./assets/css/global.css";
```

my app.scss:

```
@import "~@nativescript/theme/core";
@import "~@nativescript/theme/default";

@import "~@nativescript/theme/scss/variables";
```

My ActionItems are black when i use the default-theme, i want to set **blue** ActionItmes.

How can I achieve this?

my Actionbar:

[image]

It get's a little bit weird when i am using a wrong theme like "grey". Then the buttons are blue and even the searchbar is shown in the right way! But then all other css-settings are defect.

[image]

Comment: check in inspector what gets applied and either change this in default scss or override it - my guess is

Comment: OK. thx, i will try.

Comment: changed my default.css. It's working fine.

Comment: You could modify the variables after importing the base scss file Or assign a new class and override the attributes.

Comment: @Manoj Thank you, i will do so.